# Search function in PHP

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert a **search function** into my website, the one I found can find data from multiple columns (which is great) but the problem is that after the search results get displayed, The **text header isn't showing** (which isn't good). Does anyone know how to show the search results including the text header? I'm still new to coding, sorry.

```
<script>
function tableSearch() {
  
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("T_SJSM");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


  // Loop through all table rows AND COLUMNS, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var match = false;
    
    //Loop trough all columns
    for(var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if(td[j]) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          match = true;
        }
      }
    }
    
    //Match found in one or multiple columns
    if (match) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Well why you don't start from index 1 instead of 0 to exclude first tr ?

Comment: If your table used headers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics#adding_headers_with_th_elements) your data could be easily distinguished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip the first row (which is the header row)

So start your loop from 1

```
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've been trying to find an answer for a week and you just helped me in just a few minutes. I appreciate the help a lot 

Comment: Happen to all of us when we were new to programming. No worries. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure should be like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If your table is looking like this then you can change only one line like this:

```
tr = document.querySelector('tbody').getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

table = document.getElementById("T_SJSM");

add "T_SJSM" Id to the tbody

or start first loop (tr loop) from 1.

Comment: Yeah, i just changed the loop from 0 to 1. Thanks for helping! 